# Unable to download image as .png/.jpg using PRAW and requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, reddit, praw

I'm using Python to download memes from the /r/memes subreddit. Here's my code:

```
import praw
import requests

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id="",
                     client_secret="",
                     user_agent="",
                     username="",
                     password="")

for submission in reddit.subreddit("memes").stream.submissions(skip_existing=True):
    print(submission.url)
    
    response = requests.get(submission.url)

    file = open(submission.id, "wb")  # line 15
    file.write(response.content)
    file.close()
```

My problem comes in at line 15. I'm able to download the image, but can't figure out how to download it as a .png/.jpg. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing file format with file extension. You're downloading the images as whatever format they are and saving them to files named with the ID of the submission. So for instance, you might save an image as a file named `hjyzud`. This image will be a JPG or a PNG (or whatever format). If you want the file name to end in `.jpg` then you should change the file name you open to include that. The first parameter of `open()` is the file name to open.

Comment: For example, `file = open(submission.id + '.jpg', "wb")` will save everything with a `.jpg` file extension. This probably isn't right, since not all URLs refer to a JPG. If you want, you can take the extension from the URL: `extension = submission.url.rsplit('.')[-1]; file = open(submission.id + '.' + extension)`

Comment: Lastly, as a style and safety thing, you should use `with` blocks to open files, as described [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). This ensures that files will be properly closed.

Answer (score 0):

just documenting @jarhill0's response, you would write the image to a file like this:

```
extension = submission.url.rsplit('.')[-1]
with open(f"{submission.id}.{extension}", "wb") as file:
    file.write(response.content)
```

Comment: @Charalamm
 the extension variable is getting the extension from the end of a URL if it has one. You could change it so that it scans the more of the ul to find an appropriate extension to apply